# CORS Origin Request Blocked in android application

Tags: javascript, php, android, web-services, ionic-framework

We have developed an android application in IONIC with Angular.js.

We are testing through a browser but it is giving errors in the console.

Cross origin request blocked: the same origin policy disallows reading the remote
resource at http://example/abc/service.php (Reason: CORS Request did not succeed)

Cross origin request blocked: the same origin policy disallows reading the remote
resource at http://example/abc/service.php (Reason: Multiple CORS request did not succeed)

```
<?php
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');

error_reporting(E_ALL);



 ?>
```

Tried with Access-Control-Allow-Origin:null and Access-Control-Allow-Origin: example.com

Still not working

We are using Angular.js in android application development with **IONIC Framework**

Help! If you know!

Answer (score 0):

"jsonp"   You can have a try.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    $.ajax({
         type: "get",
         async: false,
         url: "http://example/abc/service.php ",
         dataType: "jsonp",
         jsonp: "callback",
         jsonpCallback:"flightHandler",
         success: function(json){
             alert(json.price);
         },
         error: function(){
             alert('fail');
         }
     });
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use cordova-plugin-whitelist

```
<access origin="http://example/" /> //specify your domain
```